# Conditionals in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I use conditionals in React?

Essentially, for customerClassesRemaining, I currently say "class(es)" but I want to write code that says if there's one class, use "class," and if there's more than one class, use "classes." Thanks!

```
render() {
    const loadBoxes = (
      Array.from({ length: 20 }).map((n, i) => (
        <LoadBox key={`${i}${n - 1}key`} />
      ))
    );
    const customerBoxes = !this.props.customersLessThanFive ? loadBoxes
    : this.props.customersLessThanFive.map((customer, i) => (

      if (customer.classes_remaining == 1) {
        customerClassesRemaining2 = {`${customer.classes_remaining} class left`}
      }
      else {
        customerClassesRemaining2 = {`${customer.classes_remaining} classes left`}
      }


      <CustomerFewerFiveBox
        key={customer.id}
        customerIndex={i + 1}
        customerName={`${customer.firstName} ${customer.lastName}`}
        customerClassesRemaining={`${customer.classes_remaining} class(es) left`}
        customerPackage = {customer.name}
        customerExpiration = {`Expiration: ${customer.expiration_date}`}
        
      />
    ))
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Fix it to not cause syntax errors (because there are some) and use customerClassesRemaining2 as you intended.

Comment: @EstusFlask I fixed the code using ternary operators but I'm just wondering why I can't use if-else statement like the above. What are the syntax errors? I just started learning React

Comment: Your problems aren't specific to React. You can do if-else, as long as it's valid JS. There are two problems, customerClassesRemaining2 variable isn't declared, and `= {\`${customer.classes_remaining} class left\`}` isn't valid JS syntax. Brackets are JSX syntax and needed only inside React components.

Answer (score 0):

you can try,

```
customerClassesRemaining2 = customer.classes_remaining == 1 ? `${customer.classes_remaining} class left` : `${customer.classes_remaining} classes left`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ternary operators like:

```
customerClassesRemaining={`${customer.classes_remaining} class${customer.classes_remaining > 1 ? 'es' : ''} left`}
```

Comment: Thanks! Why can't I use if-else statement? I'm brand new to react so I'm still familiarizing myself with it.

Comment: If you want to write a condition inside template literals ```(``)``` you should use ternary operators. You can use also use if-else statements but in another place